# AjaxControlToolkit PieChart Not Rendering Properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, pie-chart

Is there a bug with the AjaxControlToolkit's PieChart, or am I forgetting something. Using the sample pie chart provided with the library's sample site, I use the following structure:

```
<ajaxToolkit:PieChart ID="piePassFail" runat="server" ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth="450"
                      ChartTitle="Widget Production in the world %" ChartTitleColor="#0E426C">
        <PieChartValues>
            <ajaxToolkit:PieChartValue Category="India" Data="70"
                         PieChartValueColor="#D08AD9" />
            <ajaxToolkit:PieChartValue Category="United States" Data="30"
                         PieChartValueColor="#0E426C" />
        </PieChartValues>
</ajaxToolkit:PieChart>
```

However, having only two values is not rendering the chart properly. I've verified it in both IE9 and FF11.  If I add a third value and adjust the data to total 100, I'm golden.  I thought the PieChart was supposed to support 1 or more data elements according to the [AjaxToolkit Library's sample site](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/PieChart/PieChart.aspx).

Comment: I did some additional testing and it seems like the PieChartValue that renders over 50% of the pie breaks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving no response from the SO community, I posted over in the [ASP.Net forums](http://forums.asp.net/post/5323917.aspx). A user responded back that it is indeed a bug, which by chance was reported by another user in [Codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27373) yesterday.

So far, it has been replicated in IE9, IE10, and FF11.